# SQL Access 2010 How to DELETE rows with duplicate values for all fields but one, based on the value of the distinct field

Tags: sql, duplicates, ms-access-2010, distinct, delete-row

I have pairs of rows where the first three of four fields are the same, but the value of the fourth is different. However, every pair has a different combination of values in the first three fields than every other pair. The fourth field is a memo field which in these instances happens to be either null or 1. I want to delete the rows where it's 1 and keep the ones where it's null in that fourth field. This happened because I did a Find/Replace on some of the values of the third field, not realizing the field combination already existed. Oops.

I used the query below to show these duplicate pairs:

```
SELECT ChartNumber, CreatedAt, Field_Name
FROM [Full Patient Database]
GROUP BY ChartNumber, CreatedAt, Field_Name
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1 AND COUNT (Field_Value) < 2;
```

Here's a simplified example of the results of that query. I also included the corresponding fourth field not shown in the query results:

```
ChartNumber    CreatedAt    Field_Name  /   /  Field_Value
----------------------------------------/   /-------------
   C1         Timestamp1       F1       /   /      1
   C1         Timestamp1       F1       /   /    (null)   
   C3         Timestamp5       F4       /   /      1
   C3         Timestamp5       F4       /   /    (null)
   C8         Timestamp6       F2       /   /      1
   C8         Timestamp6       F2       /   /    (null)
   C9         Timestamp8       F1       /   /      1
   C9         Timestamp8       F1       /   /    (null)

etc
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to select or delete just the rows from the above query with a value of 1 in the fourth field. If I include the WHERE clause

```
WHERE Field_Value = '1'
```

in the above query it returns no results because it evaluates the WHERE clause before the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses. Instead I need it to apply the constraints of that WHERE clause after the rest. I'm betting this requires a subquery but can't get it to come out right.

As a related question, the Find/Replace operation also created duplicate row pairs where all four fields are the same. In these instances it's just like the above except all rows happen to have a 1 in the fourth field. I used this similar query to find and display them:

```
SELECT ChartNumber, CreatedAt, Field_Name, Field_Value
FROM [Full Patient Database]
GROUP BY ChartNumber, CreatedAt, Field_Name, Field_Value
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

How can I keep just one row in each of these pairs? No, there is no unique ID field at this point.

Thanks, appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT A.ChartNumber, A.CreatedAt, A.Field_Name
FROM [Full Patient Database] A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ChartNumber, CreatedAt, Field_Name
    FROM [Full Patient Database]
    GROUP BY ChartNumber, CreatedAt, Field_Name
    HAVING COUNT (*) > 1 AND COUNT(Field_Value) < 2
) B
on A.ChartNumber = B.ChartNumber
   and A.CreatedAt = B.CreatedAt
   and A.Field_Name = B.Field_Name
WHERE A.FIELD_VALUE = 1
```

The second question can have a simple solution in some steps:

1. Select distinct records to a temp table
2. Erase this records from original table
3. Copy the records (now distinct) back to original table
4. Remove temporary table

For sure there are ways to do it in a single step. If you want I can do it.

Comment: That worked for the first part, thanks! Your multi-step solution for the second part sounds good as well. Appreciate the super-quick response!